# WebView won't show in dialog

Tags: android, webview, dialog

I have a problem with WebView in dialog. I have tried many different tips but nothing has worked. So, my problem is that I am unable to load WebView in custom dialog. It opens dialog and gives none error but dialog won't "fill" with web view. It just shows a title of dialog.

AlertDialog.Builder does open webview in dialog but it won't open keyboard when clicking input fields. If I open keyboard it appears behind the dialog. (This seems to be known bug...)

```
Dialog alert = new Dialog(Activity.this );

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web, null);

        alert.setContentView(view);
        alert.setTitle("WebView");
        alert.setCancelable(true);

        WebView w = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web);
        w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );
        w.getSettings().setUserAgentString("useri");
        w.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        alert.show();
```

and R.layout.web file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="9999dp"
    android:minWidth="9999dp" />
```

How to open web view in dialog?

Comment: Could you show R.layout.web file?

Comment: @Piotr added R.layout.web file in main post

Comment: What is the point of these attributes?

android:minHeight="9999dp"
android:minWidth="9999dp"

Comment: @Zerkz , it was just a hopeless try to get that that view shown in dialog. Somebody in different topics gave that tip.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** set the minHeight and minWidth to such ridiculous values. Remove these and it should work. Also probably would be better to set the WebView to Fill parent so that it fills the entire Dialog (If that is what you want).

Comment: These minHeight and minWidth was just tries to get webview shown in dialog. In some topics somebody gave that tip. Also fill parent doesn't make any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding WebView programatically to Dialog instead of using XML.

Comment: Could you take a look at my similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745555/webview-with-facebook-login-flickering-in-dialog) and say if that's helpful anyhow?